# Existence of accelerated subgradient methods

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, subgradient, non-smooth-optimization

Heavy Ball method and Nesterov's gradient method are two kinds of accelerated versions of gradient methods that achieve optimal convergence for smooth optimization. I wonder whether there is an accelerated version of subgradient method. If no, can you give an intuition for why the acceleration does not work for non-smooth problems?

Answer (score 0):

The text [Accelerated Methods for the SOCP-relaxed
Component-based Distributed Optimal Power Flow](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.03468.pdf) talk about a particular problem  with an accelerated subgradient method.

Perhaps you can find another texts searching, with some math expression, to [accelerated
subgradient method](https://www.searchonmath.com/arxiv/result?q=accelerated%20%0A%20subgradient%20method%20) on SearchOnMath.